# Cannot create a query on an entity that has LocalDateTime field on MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, morphia, localdate, nosql

I can save an entity that has LocalDateTime field to datastore. However, 
I am trying to query on an entity that has LocalDateTime field. When I create a query and call asList method, the exception below is thrown:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.MappingException: No usable constructor for java.time.LocalDateTime
```

Answer (score 1):

Morphia relies on the default constructor when maps entities from MongoDB to a Java objects, as java.time.LocalDateTime class don't have one it throws the exception.

You can use @PreLoad lifecycle annotation to convert data as follows:

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity {
    public MyEntity() {

    }

    @Id
    private ObjectId id;
    private LocalDateTime localDateTime;

    @PreLoad
    public void preLoad(DBObject obj) {
        BasicDBObject object = (BasicDBObject) obj.get("localDateTime");
        BasicDBObject date = (BasicDBObject) object.get("date");
        BasicDBObject time = (BasicDBObject) object.get("time");
        localDateTime = LocalDateTime.of(date.getInt("year"),
                                         date.getInt("month"),
                                         date.getInt("day"),
                                         time.getInt("hour"),
                                         time.getInt("minute"),
                                         time.getInt("second"),
                                         time.getInt("nano"));
        obj.removeField("localDateTime");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't currently support for Java 8 date/time types in Morphia.  There is a new module currently in code review that will add this support in the 1.3 release, hopefully.